# Add extra field to an serialized Object at runtime

Tags: serialization, javassist

I want to to add an extra filed(e.g a UUID) to the Object i.e going to be serialized or already serialized at runtime using javassist or reflection.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Short answer

You cannot do it as you want but maybe there are other ways

#### Long answer

So let's start from some definitions:

**Javassist**: is a class library for editing bytecode in Java. It enables Java programs to define a new class at runtime and to `modify a given class file when the JVM loads it`.

**Reflection:** is a feature in the Java programming language. It allows an executing Java program to `examine or introspect` upon itself, and `manipulate internal properties` of the program. For example, it's possible for a Java class to obtain the names of all its members and display them.

So as I highlighted with `Javassist` you can easily add a field to a class but `only at load time` (meaning when the JVM is loading the classes into its memory).

With `reflection` instead is possible to lookup at the properties of a class and even modify them, however there is `no way off adding new properties`.

#### My proposal

I don't now if this is is feasible for your usecase but the solution may to use them both:

1. Using `Javassist` add the UUID filed to the classes that may need it at load time
2. Before serializing the object, you can use `Reflection` to actually set this UUID field to the desired value and then serialize it

Comment: my issue is i can't add it to the class directly at load time, because i am not aware of which class it is.i can get the class name using javassist at runtime , once the object is serialized.

Comment: I just want to pass an UUID with that object which is serialized. So that i can fetch it in other end of the chain , where it will be deserialized.

Comment: As I said you can use Javassist to instrument every class that implements serializable by adding an empty UUID field. Then only in the class that you need and when you need (so before serializing) you can set this field to the proper value. Into all the other classes that you changed the simple addition of one field will not change anything

Comment: Yeah well let me know how it goes :)

Comment: It didnt go as expected. I tried adding an extra field to the class that implements serializable, but the field is not being serialized. I cheked the method of ObjectStreamClass to know wheather its being serialized or not, but its not being serialized, neither does it gives an exception or error.

Comment: Ok, I don't know really how the serialization process it done by Java so I am not really sure that my proposal can actually work. Qhat about another idea: create a new class that implements serializable and has as fields a serializable object (your target) and an ID that you can use later to identify the object. This may be easier?

Comment: Even though it is easy , my job is to add the field at runtime or class loading time. I cant not directly append an extra field to it.

Comment: It worked as expected.bcz of some logical error it was not working properly before. But its working fine now. Thanx

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it is possible without reflection without needing to have any window to the Class whose object you want to add the custom property to - It can be done by first converting your object to an Attribute Map like this,

Here is a method I have written for this,

```
     /**
     * To convert the current Object to a AttributeMap. This allows for using this map
     * to add to it in a subclass additional attributes for Serialization. It would be
     * required in a scenario when you want to alter the simple Jackson Serialization
     * methodology(where you just annotate the fields to be included in Serialization
     * and that's it.). A non-simple scenario would involve adding custom fields decided
     * at runtime 
     * @return The AttributeMap of this object.
     */
    protected Map<String, Object> toAttributeMap(Object object){
        return objectMapper.convertValue(object, new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {
        });
    }
```

Now, you can add to this Attribute Map for the object and then put()-ing your fields  and convert it to maybe a JSON string.

---

**Notes about the answer:**

- It uses Jackson's Object Mapper API.
- It doesn't use JavaAssist.